# Power Virtual Agents Automatically suggest a solution before connecting to a live agent

Tags: azure, powerapps, azure-qna-maker, power-virtual-agents

I was looking for a basic ability for bot to learn from the questions and answers the agents provide that can be used as suggestion the chatbot replies to users before it connects them to live agent. I looked up QnA maker does similar stuff and can I be able to integrate it over here?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://language.cognitive.azure.com/

Click on **Create**

[image]

[image]

Choose Custom Question Answering

[image]

After creating, go to that project
Click on Edit Knowledge Base and create question and answer pairs.
After creating the Knowledge base, go to deploy the knowledge base

[image]

[image]

Click on Deploy

[image]

Create a bot and attach the existing knowledge base to bot before going to the Live Chat